# Check and comment my proof of $a+b \geq 2 \sqrt{ab}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing, solution-verification

I want to prove

> $$
> a+b \geq 2 \sqrt{ab}, \quad \text{for}  \quad a, b>0 \tag 1
> $$

*First question:*

Isn't this wrong? Shouldn't it be
$$
a+b \geq 2 \sqrt{ab}, \quad \text{for} \quad a, b\geq0 \tag 2
$$

Or
$$
a+b > 2 \sqrt{ab}, \quad \text{for} \quad a, b>0 \tag 3
$$

*And the proof:*

I start backwards.
\begin{align}
a+b-2&\sqrt{ab}\geq 0 \tag 4 \\
(\sqrt a)^2+(\sqrt b)^2-2&\sqrt{ab}\geq  0 \tag 5 \\
(\sqrt a)^2+(\sqrt b)^2-2&\sqrt{a}\cdot \sqrt{b}\geq 0 \tag 6
\end{align}
Let $x= \sqrt a$ and $y=\sqrt b$, so we see that
\begin{align}
x^2+y^2-2xy&\geq 0 \tag 7\\
(x-y)^2\geq 0 \tag 8
\end{align}
So finally we have
$$
(\sqrt a- \sqrt b)^2 \geq 0 \tag 9
$$

If $a=b=0$ we have $0\geq 0$ which is true for $0=0$ ($0>0$ is always false).

For $a>0$ and $b>0$  the square $(\sqrt a- \sqrt b)^2$ is always strictly positive.

And also, $a<0$ and $b<0$ is not valid because $\sqrt a$ and $\sqrt b$ are only defined for $a\geq 0$ and $b\geq 0$.

Comment: you also have equality when $a=b$.

Comment: "Isn't this wrong? Shouldn't it be "  No it its not wrong.  Stronger cases are subset of weaker cases.  If something is true for $a,b\ge 0$ then it is true for $a,b > 0$ and it is true for $a,b > 7$ and it is true for $a,b >29$ where $a$ is an even integer and be is the square root of a positive integer.  If "All tigers or carnivores" is true then "All tigers eat food" is *not* wrong.

Comment: Oh, and no, you can have $a=b=\sqrt ab >0$ and $a+b = 2\sqrt ab$ while $a,b > 0$.

Comment: "I start backwards." Please don't.

Comment: "For $a>0$ and $b>0$ the square $(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})^2$ is always strictly positive."  Nonsense!  Of course that isn't true! (if $a=b>0$ then $(\sqrt a -\sqrt b)^2$ is strictly positive??????)

Comment: "I start backwards" You don't know that $a+b-2\sqrt {ab}>0$. That is what you are trying to *prove*.  $(\sqrt a - \sqrt b)^2 \ge 0$ is a universal result that is 1) always true and 2) *not* what you were asked to prove in the first place.  If you "start backwords" you *must* specify what you are doing and you *MUST* state that every step is only true if it *follows* directly from the next step.  You *must* say that that is what you are doing.  Otherwise you are just assuming what you want to prove with no justification and concluding something entirely different.

Comment: @fleablood I don't think that an abundance of question (or exclamation) marks is really helpful for the OP ...

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not wrong. It is simply not as strong as it could be. Your (2) is also right, but that doesn't make (1) wrong.

However, your (3) *is* wrong: if $a=b$, then $a+b=2\sqrt{ab}$.

Answer (score 0):

I would just want to point out that in the third equation and the proof,
\begin{align} \text{for }~  a ,~  b > 0 , \ ( \sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b} )^2 \end{align}
is non-negative, since both of them could be equal.

Answer (score 0):

You want to prove $a+b \geq 2 \sqrt{ab}, \quad \text{for}  \quad a, b>0$.

You can use $a^2 > 0$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ as an assumption and segue into (9), with the restriction that $a,b > 0$. Then, instead of working backwards, you're working forwards and the proof is nice.

Rewrite your proof so that it begins with the assumptions, then (9) becomes (7) with $x = \sqrt{a}$ and $y= \sqrt{b}$ which then becomes (4), and finally conclude your proof.